# Apache karaf - How to log:display a 'lot' of information?

Tags: java, logging, osgi, apache-karaf

Working with karaf 2.2.9 on linux ubuntu servers, I have a karaf command which launches a some code. This generates some detailed functionnal log in the karaf.log
This command is executed regularly (every 2 hours).

We want to collect the log corresponding to each execution.

**What we already do :**
We have a script shell which uses the client karaf to do the following :

1. Execute log:clear ==> this puts a marker that will prevent any future log:display command to go before this marker
2. Execute our command ==> this writes things in the log
3. Execute log:display -n 0 ==> this gets the log between the previous log:clear and now
4. Writes the result in a file for later statistics and analysing

All this is repeated every two hours.

In order to not limit too much the output, I have modified the "size" parameter in karaf/etc/org.apache.karaf.log.cfg to a higher value.

**Problem :**
Sometimes, the output can be very rich (and of course, the richer it is, the more critical it becomes!).
So :

- if I put the "size" parameter too low, the log:display does not take all the required log
- if I put the "size" parameter too high, karaf hangs in an out of memory
  I have already increased karaf xmx memory.
  The documentation on the "log" commands is very poor. In fact, there is no explanation how this log system works (or I couldn't find it).

**My question :**
Is there a way to increase something so that I can take a rather comfortable amount of log between a log:clear and a log:display ?

Of course, other solutions could be considered, like remaking entirely the logging method or the program, but it would cost far much more than finding the right parameter for a system which already runs.

Answer (score 2):

The default log service used in Karaf is [ops4j pax logging](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging).

You can setup the logging-System with the file karaf/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
This is a log4j-like configuration file. Here you can setup your own appenders and loggers, adjust the file size, backup-index, etc...

This way you can extract specific logging-information into different log-files.

Comment: This is a way to configure the logging system of karaf. But it does not act on the content of what it is logged (of course, this is the role of the app). Even if it is tuned, the "log:display" will fail short if the content is too heavy. I need to capture around 5-6Mo of log (I don't need hundreds of Mo!), and it would seem odd if it is not doable.